# issue with calling function in python with positional argument

Tags: python, function

[image]

what is causing issue in the code? here is the text of the code

```
import numpy as np
class Solution():
    def findMedianSortedArrays(n1,n2):
        a=0
        n1=np.array(n1)
        n2=np.array(n2)
        sum1=0
        n3=n1+n2
        for i in n3:
            sum1=sum1+i
            a=a+1
        return (sum1/a)
```

Comment: When you call an instance method, the first argument is `self`, the object the method is bound to. If your method doesn't need `self`, it probably shouldn't be a method.

Comment: As an addition to to @khelwood, if the method on a class doesn't need any class attributes then you can make it a static class method by adding `@staticmethod` above the `findMedianSortedArrays` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first default argument to a class method is `self`, in other words, the class instance itself. In your code, the `n1` is going to take the value of the class instance, and `n2` is going to take the value of `1`, and there is no argument left for value `2`, thus the error is thrown.

You can try print out your `n1` and `n2` to understand what I meant.

Solution:

```py
def findMedianSortedArrays(self,n1,n2):
    ...
```

If you don't want to pass `self`, implement the method as `staticmethod`, like this:

```py
@staticmethod
def findMedianSortedArrays(n1,n2):
    ...
```

This way, function call to `findMedianSortedArrays` can work with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The function invocation:

```
sum1 = Solution().findMedianSortedArrays(1, 2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
solution = Solution()
sum1 = solution.findMedianSortedArrays(1, 2)
```

Quoting from here: [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

> The first argument of every class method, including init, is always a
> reference to the current instance of the class. By convention, this
> argument is always named ***self***. In the init method, self refers to the
> newly created object; in other class methods, it refers to the
> instance whose method was called.

TLDR:

Use

```
def findMedianSortedArrays(self, n1, n2):
    ...
```

or make a static invocation:

```
sum1 = Solution.findMedianSortedArrays(1, 2)
```